# when using react useEffect my app is crashing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i m changing a class component to a functional component and i m using hooks and useEffect so my app becoms really slow and crushs without any error

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';

const FancyToolBar = ({ children }) => {
  const [backGround, togglebackGround] = useState('white');
  const listenScrollEvent = () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 80) {
      togglebackGround('black');
    } else {
      togglebackGround('white');
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', listenScrollEvent);
  });
  const logo = backGround === 'white'
    ? <img src="/images/1.jpg" alt="" style={{ width: '50px !important', height: '50px' }} />
    : <img src="/images/2.png" alt="" style={{ width: '50px !important', height: '50px' }} />;
  return (
    <Toolbar style={{ backgroundColor: backGround }}>
      {logo}
      {children}
    </Toolbar>
  );
};


export default FancyToolBar;
```

Comment: whats the error message

Comment: what version of React? you must have most recent to use Hooks

Answer (score 5):

There are two things that you need to address.

**First:** you need to cleanup your `eventListener`.

**Second:** only add the event listener on initial mount by adding `[]` as the second parameter to useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', listenScrollEvent);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', listenScrollEvent);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you! The second answer helped me with my infinite problem :)

Comment: Thank you Mister! this answer saved my head